# Problem with contentblocker in appwebview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview, safari-content-blocker

hi i try block ads using ContentBlocker but but it doesn't work , i try with androidShouldInterceptRequest and it working fine but not available on ios
for test i just try block all url contains "voiranime" and i use that regex ".*voiranime.*" but not working

```
contentBlockers:[
           ContentBlocker(
               trigger: ContentBlockerTrigger(urlFilter: ".*voiranime.*",),
               action: ContentBlockerAction(
                   type: ContentBlockerActionType.BLOCK
               )
           ),
         ],
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to prevent ads or popups???

Comment: @MartinWittick i add answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android**

```
InAppWebView(
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldInterceptRequest: true,
    ),
),
androidShouldInterceptRequest: (controller, request) async {
  var url = request.url.toString();
  var i = 0;
  while(i<adblock.length){
    if(url.contains(adblock.elementAt(i))){
      return WebResourceResponse();
    }
    i++;
  }
});
```

my variable adblock is just list for filter like that

```
List<String> ads(){
List<String> list = [];
list.add("imasdk.googleapis.com");
list.add("rtmark.net");
list.add("offerimage.com");
list.add("xadsmart.com");
list.add("cloudfront.net");
list.add("in-page-push.com");
return list;}
```

you can add others if you want

**Ios**

you must use ContentBlocker with regex